# How to sort ResourceSet in C#

Tags: c#, resources, asp.net-3.5

I have a resource file named filetypes.resx. Some how I figured out to bind the resource values to dropdownlist, but I don't know how to sort the values of **ResourceSet**.

Here is what I did so far,

**FileTypes.resx**

- Name,Value
- A,1
- B,2
- C,3

**code to bind dropdownlist**

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = Resources.FileTypes.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Key";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Value";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

**Result**

```
 A
 C
 B
```

```
As you can see the result is not sorted. Please help me to solve this issue.
```

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ressource set has a IDictionaryEnumerator so I guess that its items are of type DictionaryEntry, try to sort the data source like this :

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = Resources.FileTypes.ResourceManager
    .GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true)
    .OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
    .OrderBy(i => i.Value);
```

Hum, I have no visual studio opened so don't blame me in case it does not work immediatly :)

Answer (score 1):

`ResourceSet` has [a property named Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourceset.table.aspx), of type [HashTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx). Maybe you could generate a sorted list out of that table (manually, or by using LINQ), then assign this list to `DropDownList1.DataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hashtable tbl = Resources.FileTypes.ResourceManager.
GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true).Table;
List source = new List(tbl.Values);
source.Sort();
DropDownList1.DataSource = source;
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. 
Please edit your answer to add some explanation.