# How to Sort items in a Resource File

Tags: c#

I have a resource file that I am looping through to add the items into a `List`, and I am trying to figure out how it decides which item to put at index[0], [1], etc

My code is as follows:

```
...

List<string> Questions= new List<string>();

ResourceManager resources = new ResourceManager(typeof(QuestionResource));
ResourceSet resourceSet = resources.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);

foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
    {
        Questions.Add(entry.Value.ToString());
    }

result.Data = Questions;

....
```

Now my list isn't coming back in Alphabetical order and its not coming back in the same order as they are listed in the resource file.

I would like to display them in the list, the same way they are displayed in the resource file, which isn't alphabetical.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Since it's a List<T> you can use the `.Sort()` Method on the List have you tried that..?

Comment: I can use `.Sort()` but I want to Sort them by the order they are in the resource file.

Comment: @Steve for that you can use an array, or alter the Sort method if you have a logic to the sort in the resource file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700240/how-to-sort-resourceset-in-c-sharp). I don't think ResourceSet methods guarantee sorting by default, but they should be stable (the order should be the same every time you do something with them), so the order that they're grabbed by foreach might not be what you'd intuitively think it would be.

You should be able to use the method in answer to the linked question to sort it how you like.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it put me on the right track.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
result.Data = Questions.OrderBy(a => a);
```

this will order it in ascending order

Comment: that sorts them alphabetically, not quite what I am looking for

Comment: you can use stack of string instead

 Stack<string> lst = new Stack<string>();
                lst.Push("value");

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but how would that help me to display by the same order in the resource file?

Comment: you want it alphabetically or the same order in the resource file?
if you have the resource file of the following records

a,b,c,d

the you use .Add() method to fill the list , then the result will be in reverse order i.e d,c,b,a

Comment: same order as I have in the resource file