# Sorting an image list loaded from resources by name

Tags: c#, sorting, visual-studio-2013

Say you have a `List<Image>`, you add all the images found in the solution's resources using something like this;

```
using (ResourceSet resourceSet = SomeProject.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true))
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
            {
                SomeList.Add((Image)entry.Value);
            }
        }
```

In this case, there'll be three images in our resources. `Apple.png Banana.png, Cactus.png`

How can I sort this list alphabetically so I can loop through it in the right order, getting `Apple -> Banana -> Cactus`?

I've read [How to sort ResourceSet in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700240/how-to-sort-resourceset-in-c-sharp) which I tried to apply to my situation but to no avail.

By myself I've tried assigning `entry.Key` to the Image's tag and then doing `someList.OrderBy(f => f.Tag).ToList();`

Here's the full code which I use to test this

```
    List<Image> someList = new List<Image>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (ResourceSet resourceSet = WindowsFormsApplication52.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true))
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
            {
                Image i = (Image)entry.Value;
                i.Tag = entry.Key;
                someList.Add((Image)i);
            }

            someList.OrderBy(f => f.Tag).ToList();
        }

        foreach(var x in someList)
        {
            PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
            pb.Image = x;
            pb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
            pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);
        }
    }
```

This is the result I seem to get every time,
[image: http://puu.sh/c5BTz/41f828cf1b.jpg]

I don't know if it takes file size into account but in this case the file sizes of the images are also in order. (Apple.png is the largest, cactus is the smallest).

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use a sorted dictionary to do the sorting for you. Simply add all the files to it with the names as the key. Then do a foreach and loop through to retrieve everything in alphabetical order.

Comment: Have you looked at what the `Tag` property's value is on each item and confirmed they are correctly named `Apple`, `Banana` and `Cactus`?

Comment: @deathismyfriend I didn't even know of it's existence, I changed my list to a sorted dictionary as you said and.. it's sorted! Thank you very much. I would mark your comment as answer if I could. 
Dave Zych Yes, I did, the tags were set correctly.

Comment: @stella. I made it an answer. If you want to accept it it is appreciated. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all images to sorted dictionary with the image name as key. 
Then you do a foreach on the dictionary to retrieve the images in alphabetical order by name.