# Why does my foreach loop automatically jump to the third value in the collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, collections

I've come across something very peculiar, I'm utilizing resource files for string translation on a work project, and at the moment I have a piece of code which iterates through those resource files to find the localized versions of the Questions and Answers pertaining to a FAQ page, then loop through them and render them on a page.

The trouble is, one of my loops works perfect, but the other simply skips straight to Answer2!

My code is below, I really can't understand why 2 pieces of code exactly the same yield different results!

```
if (LanguageStrings.Culture == null)
{
    LanguageStrings.Culture = new CultureInfo("en-gb");
    LanguageStrings_FAQ.Culture = new CultureInfo("en-gb");
    LanguageStrings_FAQAnswers.Culture = new CultureInfo("en-gb");
}

CultureInfo ResxCulture = new CultureInfo(LanguageStrings.Culture.Name);
List<string> FAQQuestions = new List<string>();

ResourceSet RS = LanguageStrings_FAQ.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(ResxCulture, true, true);

foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in RS)
{
    FAQQuestions.Add(entry.Value.ToString());
}

List<string> FAQAnswers = new List<string>();

ResourceSet RSAnswers = LanguageStrings_FAQAnswers.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(ResxCulture, true, true);

foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in RSAnswers)
{
    FAQAnswers.Add(entry.Value.ToString());
}
```

The first item in RS is 0, which has a key of Questions0 as I'd expect, but in the second loop index 0 is Answers2!

Could anyone give me a pointer as to why this situation is occurring?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get the "wrong" element of the collection because `ResourceSet` is *unordered*:

> The `ResourceSet` class enumerates over an `IResourceReader`, loading every name and value, and storing them in a `Hashtable`.

Whenever a `HashTable` is used, the order of iteration is unspecified. If you would like your resources to come in a specific order, you need to order them yourself, for example, by applying `OrderBy` by some property.

Comment: Is there a way to order it?

Comment: An old post - but to sort the ResourceSet read ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700240/how-to-sort-resourceset-in-c-sharp

Comment: @ReeceCottam Please see Paul's comment. The answer at the link shows how to apply `OrderBy` to get the data ordered on strings representing resource keys.

Comment: @ReeceCottam Don't cast to `ResourceSet`. Replace `ResourceSet RS` with `var rs`, and `foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in RS)` with `foreach (var entry in rs)` to make the code compile.